# View a List on a Subsite or Parent Site

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, sub-site

My question is about Sharepoint Server 2013. I have a created a list web part from a Subsite by using Sharepoint Designer to save a Data View Web part of my list and exported it to the Site Gallery. When I go to a different Subsite in the same site collection and try to add this web part I am able to select the web part I created but when I click save I keep getting this error.

[image]

However , I can add the web part I created on the same site I exported it from. I cannot figure out what is going on. Through several searches, I have tried the following: Turned Allow management of content types to No. I have inherited permissions from the Parent Site so everyone has the same permission. I have permission to see all so that shouldn't be the problem anyway. Any ideas?? I really need this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior, you can use the web part on the same site but other sites you can't because the **list ID** does not exist in the other sites **(list scope is per site).**

---

**Regarding,** displaying a SharePoint list from Parent site in a subsite, you have the below tow options:

1. Using Data View Web Part. check the details steps in this thread [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657#226657)
2. `Content Query Web Part` as the following :

   - Edit your current Page > Click on Add web Part > below Content Rollup > Add Content Query Web Part .

[image]

- Click to open the tool pane to edit
- At Query section, > at Show items from the following list: > click browse to browse any list from any site below your site collection.

[image]

Although this method will achieve your goal to show a list from another site, unfortunately, it will need some customization (ItemStyle) to show your CQWP as List view, and to can do this check [SharePoint Content Query web part like a SharePoint List View](https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/sharepoint-content-query-web-part-like-a-sharepoint-list-view/)

---

**Check the details steps at**

- [How to display a sharepoint list from parent site in subsite?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657#226657)

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution for this. Create the webpart with sharepoint designer, or just edit the code that is generated in the page. The, get the WebId of the site that contains the list, and edit the webpart so it contains the following tag, inside the **XsltListViewWebPart**:

```
WebId="[your source site webId here]"
```

To get the webId you will need to connect to the site using powershell and get the WebId by console.

References:

- [Adding webId to a webpart.](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/07/creating-an-xslt-list-view-web-part-from-a-different-site.html)
- [Get webid with Powershell](http://anthony-verschraegen.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/sharepoint-powershell-get-web-id-guid.html)