# SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2016, sub-site

I need to display a list from a parent (really the site collection) on a sub-site. I've found multiple answers referencing this [link](http://sharepointontop.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-listview-webpart-from-parent-site.html). However, this post is from 2012 and discusses a solution for SharePoint 2010.

Does this still work in SharePoint 2016 (on-premise)? If not, is there a replacement solution?

Comment: Check also my detail article at **[Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**To show list view from Parent site at subsite in SP 2013 / 2016, You have two options**

1. Using `Data View Web Part`
2. Using `Content Query Web Part`

---

**(1) Using Data View Web Part**

- Open your Parent site via SharePoint Designer 2013.
- Go to File Site Pages > Create a new Page > Edit in advanced mode.
- From the above ribbon > Insert > Data View > Select the list that you need to show on the subsite.

> In case the data view is disabled check [DATAVIEW IS DISABLED IN
>   SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/19/dataview-is-disabled-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

- Once the Data view add, from the above ribbon > `List View Tool` > Web Part > Click on `To Site Gallery`.

[image]

> In case you are missing `List View Tool` check [MISSING LIST VIEW TOOLS IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/18/missing-list-view-tools-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

- Make sure that you clicked on Yes at the below dialog to make sure that it will show the list data from the parent site URL

[image]

- Now open your subsite > Create a new page > edit the page > add new web part > At Miscellaneous category > the exported data view web part should be listed > Add it.

[image]

**OutPut**

[image]

> To show Toolbar > Edit your web part > and select `Show ToolBar` not
>   Full toolbar

---

**(2) Using Content Query Web Part**

In case you need to query data from a parent site, you can use the **Content Query Web Part** as a supported OOTB solution.

[image]

> **Note:** The CQWP is only available in **Publishing Template** or
>   `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature activated,

**Steps**

- Open your Page > Click on Add web Part > below Content Rollup > Add Content Query Web Part .
- Click to open the tool pane to edit
- At Query section, > at Show items from the following list: > click browse to browse any list from any site below your site collection.
- Select the list that you need from the parent site.

[image]

Now you just need to show the CQWP as Grid with your required column, in this case, check this article [SharePoint Content Query web part like a SharePoint List View](https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/sharepoint-content-query-web-part-like-a-sharepoint-list-view/)

---

**If you don't have Publishing Template, you will need to**

- Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` at the site collection feature.

[image]

- Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing` at the site feature.

[image]

> But you should note that activating these features will lead to
>   missing the Save site as a template. For more details check [MISSING
>   SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Comment: Check also my detailed article at [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)